# Could we change subject of SMS in PHP Twilio Api

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I have implemented twilio Api in PHP and its working fine.
But i am getting SMS on phone with Subject **DM-012362**.

For Example:

DM-012362
My message....

Could i change DM-012362 to DM-ABCD

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You need to get the Permission From twillio and give him a Sender id DM-ABCD after the approval this is change***